# How is the voting mechanism and FDI algorithm applied in transport aircraft?

Tags: avionics, aircraft-certification, inertial-nav-system, transport-category, air-data-computer

How is the voting mechanism applied in modern transport airplanes for airdata/inertial reference sensors fault detection and isolation (FDI)?

Are there any other FDI methods approved by the regulators to use on the commercial aircraft? Like Kalman filter based FDI algorithms?

Comment: For Air/IR data on Airbus see: [Do redundant angle of attack and sideslip sensors use a voting mechanism, or do they display data directly?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/88872/3201) and [How does the Airbus flight computer's voting system work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15234/3201) (for early closers, they are not duplicates)